# RAM USAGE at lowest level possible in linux for an embedded system

Tags: c, linux, embedded

I am working on ARM processor based system which runs linux. I have an application running on it which is based on Qt. This Qt application is linked with static library which is my main concern. This Qt app invokes threads from this library.

I want to know the RAM used by the threads which are invoked from the library.
Please note that I want RAM usage from those invoked from this library alone not Qt.

Thanks in advance!

Regards,
Rocky.

Answer (score 0):

How about `ps -m -o rss,vsz`?